# Glow around the sides of a rectangle

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiview, core-graphics

I am trying to create glow just around the sides of the rectangle.  The rest of the rectangle should be filled clear color.  I create a `UIView` with `CGRect` of certain size and then -

```
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:203/255.0 green:1.0 blue:252/255.0 alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    int glowSpread = 2;
    CGRect glowRect = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x-glowSpread, self.bounds.origin.y-glowSpread, self.bounds.size.width+2*glowSpread, self.bounds.size.height+2*glowSpread);
    self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:glowRect cornerRadius:5.0].CGPath;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:203/255.0 green:1.0 blue:252/255.0 alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
```

With the above approach, I get the glow around the side but the whole `CGRect` gets filled with the shadow color, which I do not want.  Any suggestion?

Comment: I tried this once and this is closer than I got, so +1 for the question.  My solution ended up to just make a glowing rectangle image and apply it using resizableImageWithCapInsets.

Answer (score 0):

make a more complicated shadow path that isn't enclosed, or just add a sublayer of the color you want.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by more complicated path? Also, how a sublayer would help?